# One smoke domain, 2 sources -> result rendered separately

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation

**Blender 2.83 - Cycles**

I have two meshes as smoke sources and I want the smoke generated from them to interact with each other (therefore 1 domain)

I also want to render the smoke emited from these 2 sources separately, which begs the question:

**Is it even possible?**

[image]

I have some wind and turbulence in the scene so 2 separate domains in 2 view layers doesn't really solve my problem (I think)

Thanks for any input!

Comment: To render each effector and domain use instances of in different collections and view layers.

Comment: Don't forget the last 2 lines in the post: "I have some wind and turbulence in the scene so 2 separate domains in 2 view layers doesn't really solve my problem". Having different view layers will prevent the smoke simulations from interacting with each other, and I require that effect to happen.